# REST Api returning XML rather than JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am trying to make a REST GET call via the **ajax** jquery function.  I am requesting that the results be returned via JSON format.  Instead, it is being returned via XML, and I am unsure why. Is my code the issue? What else can affect JSON requests? NOTE: the site is an https site if that makes any difference.

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/sites/****/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('ImageList')/Items",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; odata=verbose',
        success: function (data) {
            //do things
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //do other things
        }
    });
```

Comment: Paste the REST url in a browser and find out what's being returned.

Comment: 'dataType: "json"' doesn't tell the server what to send, it tells jQuery what to expect from the server.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: What does the code at /Items do? how are you actually returning the data - just because you specified the content type does not mean that it will be returned that way - you need to specify the correct return type in your /Items function

Comment: Where are you making the request?

Comment: Clearly the server is returning XML rather than JSON, meaning it's a server issue not related to your javascript (unless you're using the wrong api endpoint, which again isn't a problem with your code, just your usage of the api.)

Comment: @SlipperyPete the `contentType`/`Accept` are sent to the server in the headers. But the server can bypass that.

Comment: The server can take hints of what to return, but ultimately what it returns is up to the server, not your code.

Comment: When I go to my REST endpoint with the included headers, it returns JSON. It apparently does not return that to my REST call even though including the **"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"** should be requesting json formatting.

Comment: I am making this request on page load, in order to get info from an external sharepoint list.

Comment: Sharepoint REST services will return JSON so the server-side is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your endpoint is specified to *return* Json, it won't.  The endpoint your utilizing is returning Xml because that particular URL is designed to send that back. Your code is correct, the API at the URL you're connecting is obviously sending the content that URL is supposed to.

Your `content-type` doesn't mean it will *return* Json, it simply states *this type* is what you should expect.

Since we can't validate or test any data really, you should look at:

- Endpoint - What is the data it should return (URL).
- Is the documentation on the API accurate, using proper URL?

Comment: Passing the server during the call the _Accept_ and _contentType_ headers to the server during the GET call should prompt the server to return JSON formatted data, but it is not. The endpoint is correct and the API docs are correct as they have worked elsewhere on my site before with a similar config.

Comment: If I build an API and I only want to spit XML, I don't care what you send me I'll spit out XML.  You need to be positive that the API will actually spit out JSON.

Comment: @GaryStorey Yeah, but where did he say he is using Share Point?

Comment: @Greg He didn't.  I work with the Sharepoint REST API all the time.  I recognize the URL in the code sample.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake in forgetting to write that into my post.  The server side should not be an issue.